# Access the latest state from external function React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple React component (Hooks):

```
// inside React component

import { someExternalFunction } from "functions"

const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

const handleChange = () => {
    someExternalFunction(value, setValue)
}

// outside of React component

const someExternalFunction = (value, setValue) => {

    console.log(value) // 0

    // testing "set" method    

    setValue(100) // working

    // "set" is async, so lets wait

    // testing "get" method 
    setTimeout(() => console.log(value), 5000) // 0

    // not working 
}
```

PROBLEM: "value"/state is always the same, it is captured at the moment when state is passed to a function.

QUESTION: How to access the latest state in external function?

CLARIFICATION: Of course it is not working with the "value"/state, I just tried to illustrate the problem that I'm facing with preferred method for providing the latest state to the function (trouh the direct reference) .

Comment: It is not that set is async, it's because you are logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) Not sure why you can't use `100` as that is what you set the value to in the same function.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't trigger "handleChange" again, the function won't use the new value. Your state is a number so it will not pass a reference but rather the value itself (in this case 0). When you call setValue, the state is updated but your timeOut callback still uses the stale value that was passed when you triggered "handleChange".

If you want to react to a state change a useEffect hook would be better.
You can also simply put a console.log(value) below the line where you define the state, to check if it changes.

// Update:

```js
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

const handleChange = () => {
  setValue(100);
}

React.useEffect(() => console.log(value), [value]);
```

Or if you want to move that logic to a reusable hook:

```js
// useExternalFunction.js
export useExternalFunction = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setValue(100);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => console.log(value), [value]);

  return {value, handleChange};
}

// component

const {value, handleChange} = useExternalFunction();

return <button onClick={handleChange}>{value}</button>;
```

Comment: I'm looking for an option to access the state from `external` function

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. When you need to react to a state change you should use an effect. If you need the updated value in your external function, then you don't need the state.

Depending on your actual use case I could try to give more hints as to how to tackle your problem but this example is in itself not really much to work with..

Comment: @jay_dtr I've added an example how to use the useEffect hook here.

Answer (score 0):

Value is primitive type, not reference type, it was pass into function as a copied value, of cause it is never changed. And setTimeout always access a copied value.